# SQL query to get most

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database with the following tables:

```
Employee (EmpID, FirstName, LastName, RegionID)
EmployeeSkills(EmpID, SkillID) [this is a linking table for the M:N relationship between Employees and skills]
Skills(SkillID, Description)
```

I need to list the name of the skill that most employees have. I tried doing a `max(count(skillID))`, sqlserver said that you can't do an aggregate function on an aggregate function. Any other ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    SkillID, s.Description,COUNT(SkillID) AS CountOf
    FROM EmployeeSkills   e
        INNER JOIN Skills s ON e.SkillID=s.SkillID
    GROUP BY SkillID, s.Description
    ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

This will return the top SkillsId with how many times it appears:

```
SELECT TOP 1 SkillID, COUNT(SkillID)
FROM EmployeeSkills
GROUP BY SkillID
ORDER BY COUNT(SkillID) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need to know how many times each one appears - I need to return the skill that the most employees have.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.Description, COUNT(*) from EmployeeSkills es
    INNER JOIN Skills s on s.SkillID = es.SkillID
GROUP BY s.Description ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

That will give you a description of the skill, and how many employees have it.

Comment: You probably want something more like this
SELECT s.Description, COUNT(*) from EmployeeSkills es
    INNER JOIN Skills s on s.SkillID = es.SkillID
GROUP BY s.Description
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC

Answer (score 0):

The following query will return the skill ID is that is used the most:

```
  SELECT TOP 1 SkillID, COUNT(SkillID)
    FROM EmployeeSkills
GROUP BY SkillID
ORDER BY COUNT(SkillID) DESC
```

You can then use that to get the name of the skill.

Comment: @Justin - The question is for SQL Server, not MySQL.